# Entity Framework 6.1 converts OR sequence to IN query introducing a huge performance hit

Tags: sql, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6, contains

I have a list of statuses (6) to find entries and my query is the following to make it cachable and avoid recompilation:

```
from u in db.Users
where u.Status == "Status1" || u.Status == "Status2" || ... u.Status == "Status6"
select u
```

It worked absolutely fine until today, I've released an update without modifying the query and without updating any library, it was just a static text change not related to the query at all but now but the query in runtime is different and causes a huge performance hit:

```
SELECT u.* FROM USERS u WHERE u.Status in ("Status1", "Status2", ... "Status6")
```

Why EF6.1 started to translate my `OR` query to `IN` query and another question how to prevent it and make I won't get this behavior in future?

Comment: There is no difference in SQL Server between `status = 's1' or status = 's2'` and `status in ('s1', 's2')` there must be some other problem

Comment: Maybe `u.*` in the second query?

Comment: this is simplified query and the original query is much bigger, I just cannot post it here. It used to work for 10-15 milliseconds and it takes a second to execute.

Comment: I agree - there is no difference. Perhaps it's a parameter sniffing issue or stale statistics.

Comment: But yes - there is a difference in that it will probably use a new plan because it's different textual SQL

Answer (score 1):

Probably till now this:

```
where u.Status == "Status1" || u.Status == "Status2" || ... u.Status == "Status6"
```

got to the database as `WHERE OR x OR y OR z`.

EF 6.1 probably tries to optimize that query as you have only Status column in your `WHERE OR` clause and sends that to the database as `WHERE IN`.

I suppose that `WHERE IN` optimization it's just syntactic sugar as query plans are equal.

As far as i know, there is no difference in SQL Server between `WHERE OR` and `WHERE IN` because when it's get executed, `WHERE IN` gets transformed in multiple ORs (conceptually).

You can try to index that column and re-view execution plan.

Otherwise the problem isn't specific to this column or to `WHERE` clause.

Other problem can appear if you have `WHERE` clauses over multiple columns (some indexed, some not indexed) and only re-view-ing your execution plans can help you here.

Comment: it's 11 pages of T-SQL and execution plan is to be learned and root cause find. It seems that after the release entity framework re-compiled the query and it triggered different execution plan causing major performance issue. I guess I couldn't control the execution plan, so I need to make my query more predictable in terms of the execution plan, indexes usage, etc.

Comment: One idea for bringing more context (just for testing purposes) is to create a sproc using those 11 pages of TSQL, check the execution plan, then recompile the execution plan and check it again. Maybe you'll spot something.

Comment: Yep, already following this plan, comparing execution plan from the query, trying to find the bottlenecks.